# Dockerfile build error: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am building a Docker image using mariadb with this setup:

```
tree
.
├── Dockerfile
└── db-load-script.sql
```

this is the contents of the Dockerfile

```
FROM mariadb:latest

COPY db-load-scripts.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

RUN apt-get update

EXPOSE 3306
```

using this build command:

```
docker build -t "mariadb" .
```

This is the error output:

```
 => ERROR [2/3] COPY db-load-scripts.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/                                                                                                   0.0s
------
 > [2/3] COPY db-load-scripts.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:
------
Dockerfile:3
--------------------
   1 |     FROM mariadb:latest
   2 |
   3 | >>> COPY db-load-scripts.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
   4 |
   5 |     RUN apt-get update
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref dd0035a4-ee11-44f5-a9fa-59de78475c9a::81lvkvf8xvbf80zrq7wng4gjc: "/db-load-scripts.sql": not found
```

What is the cause of this COPY error?

Comment: please put `db-load-scripts.sql` file in the same folder of your `Dockerfile`

Answer (score 1):

Based in your information, your COPY command is trying to find a file in plural "db-load-scripts.sql" and your file is in singular "db-load-script.sql"